# Convert string to dictionary in Python2

Tags: python-2.7

Considering the following string:

```
u'A:1\r\nB:2'
```

How one can transform this Unicode string to a dictionary in Python2?

Comment: its dictionary not directory

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
str = u'A:1\r\nB:2'
dict = {}
for i in str.split("\r\n"):
    dict[i[0]] = i[2]
```

And u will get : {u'A': u'1', u'B': u'2'}

Answer (score 0):

You can import `ast`,  and use it like that :

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("{'a' : '1', 'b' : '2'}")
{'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
```